# Installed GRASS Addons not appearing under modules [windows 10, grass 7.4.0]

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.4

I have installed GRASS 7.4.0 and then use the console to install the addons, r.denoise and r.patch.smooth.

However, when I want to run these tools there is nothing under the addons section in the modules tab.

[image: Addons installed but not appearing]

Comment: Even after you restart the GUI? The addons should show up after restarting GUI.

Comment: Yes even after restarting the GUI.